# Do several commands concerning a list of objects by iterating only once on an object list in Python

Tags: python, list

Helllo, sorry if my question has already been answered, i didn't find it...

I have a list of objects called `structList`

Here is the structure of my objects:

```py
class ResponseStructure():
    def __init__(self, isSucceededRequest: bool, latency: float, date: datetime, comment: str) -> None:
        self.isSucceededRequest = isSucceededRequest
        self.latency = latency
        self.date = date
        self.comment = comment
```

I'm actually trying to create a function to iterate over `structList` and return a dictionnary containing some data.

Here is an example of the output I'd like to have:

```py
{
    # The minimum value for all object 'lat' attributes in the object list and the corresponding date
    'minLat': (0.2, "12/24/2018-04:59:31"),

    # The maximum value for all object 'lat' attributes in the object list and the corresponding date
    'maxLat': (4.2, "6/21/2019-05:56:32"),

    # The mean value for all object 'lat' attributes in the object list
    'meanLat': (0.6),

    # Total number of isSuccess==True attributes in the object list
    'isSuccessNumber' : 1234,

    # Total number of com=="Error" attributes in the object list
    'numberOfError' : 123 
}
```

**I'm able to create this function, however, i don't know how to do it by iterating only ONCE on the object list.**

```py
# HERE IS MY ORIGINAL CODE, I'VE PASTED IT BECAUSE SOMEONE ASKED IT
def generateReport(structList: List[ResponseStructure]) -> Dict:
    report = {}

    # Minimum latency
    minLatStruct = min(structList, key=lambda struct: struct.latency)
    report['minLat'] = (minLatStruct.latency, f"{minLatStruct.date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S')}")

    # Maximum latency
    maxLatStruct = max(structList, key=lambda struct: struct.latency)
    report['maxLat'] = (maxLatStruct.latency, f"{maxLatStruct.date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M:%S')}")
    
    # Mean latency
    report['meanLat'] = statistics.mean([struct.latency for struct in structList])
    
    # Number of code 200
    report['isSuccessNumber'] = sum(struct.isSucceededRequest == True for struct in structList)
    
    # Number of Error
    report['numberOfError'] = sum(struct.comment == "Error" for struct in structList)
    
    return report
```

**I'm iterating 5 times on the list, and i want to iterate only once, if possible.**

Is there a way to do it ? Thanks for your answers !

Comment: @KyleParsons I've edited my topic, you can now find my code I want to optimize =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is

```
dataDict = {'minLat': (90, None), 'maxLat':(-90, None), 'isSuccessNumber':0,'numberOfError':0}
#this is assuming lat goes from -90 to 90, and that you can at least one item
count = 0
totalLat = 0
for item in testList:
   count +=1
   totalLat += item.lat
   dataDict['isSuccessNumber'] += item.isSuccess
   dataDict['numberOfError'] += (item.com == 'Error')
   if item.lat > dataDict['maxLat'][0]:
       dataDict['maxLat'] = (item.lat, item.date)
   if item.lat < dataDict['minLat'][0]:
       dataDict['minLat'] = (item.lat, item.date)
dataDict['mean'] = totalLat/count
```

However, I'm not sure this will be faster than doing `max([(item.lat, item.date) for item in testList], key = lambda x: x.lat)`, etc.

Comment: That seems alright to me. This is a way of iterating once. It will still be faster than my first try which I iterated 5 times on my list ...
By the way, it was about latency, not latitude, I edited my post to avoid confusion. I upvoted, but it is not displayed because I am a baby on stack overflow =)
Thank you !

Comment: Since `lat` is latency, you can make the initial values for min and max `float('inf')` and `float('-inf')` instead.

Comment: @KyleParsons Yeah, thanks, gonna do this.

Comment: @Acccumulation I've tried over 50,000,000 entries. Your solution is 4.7 times faster than mine, as expected.